# Powershell script involving AD users and luhn algorithm

Tags: powershell, luhn

I'm a Powershell newbie, and I need help with a script.
I need to list all AD users with their employee ID, and I need a csv with a column which will state if the Employee ID is true or false according to Luhn algorithm test.
I have this script:

```
import-module -Name ActiveDirectory

$SearchBaseOU = "OU=---,DC=---,DC=---"

$ADusers = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase $SearchBaseOU -Properties EmployeeID,CanonicalName,EmployeeNumber | 
   Where {$_.EmployeeID -eq "123456789"} | 
   Select-Object samAccountName, Name , EmployeeID, EmployeeNumber,@{name="OU";expression={(($_.CanonicalName.split('/'))[0..($_.CanonicalName.split('/').Count-2)]) -join '/'}}

$ADusers | Export-Csv .\EnabledInactiveUsers.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

This script lists all AD users with employee ID which equals to "123456789".
I also found this script online:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/gibbels-algorithms/1.0.3/Content/scripts%5Cluhn%5CTest-LuhnValidation.ps1

which tests if the ID is true or false.

My question is - How do I take the luhn algorithm function and add it to the original script above to make the test and export the results into true or false statements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-5.1)

For Example, see the last property in the select: "IsLuhn" like you used in the CanonicalName property in your example,
Add the Luhn function from the link to your code first.

```
$ADusers = Get-ADUser[... -Properties EmployeeID,CanonicalName,EmployeeNumber ...] | 
Select EmployeeID,CanonicalName,EmployeeNumber,
@{N="IsLuhn";E={Test-LuhnValidation $_.EmployeeID}}
```

Comment: Thanks! We managed to get it to work. Much appreciated!